# How do I increase my image width and height according to the viewport of the user while keeping the aspect ratio same?

Tags: html, css, viewport

I'm making a website and the website is basically just a huge image except for the clickable elements and I was wondering how I could make the image size increase according to the the user's screen size so that the image doesn't look stretched, but still fits the whole screen. This is my first time working with viewport, so I can't exactly say I understand it very well. Here's some code to help out:

```
<div class="Image">
          <img src="Background.png"/> 
        </div>

.Image {
    width: 100vw;
    height:  100vh;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

The first part was written in index.html while the second was written in style.css. Just for your info, the html part was written in `<body>`.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Comment: Use `width:100vw` `height:100vh` and `object-fit: according to wish` but recommended to use `contain`

Comment: @Rana I tried out what you said, but it didn't change anything. I hope I'm not wrong, but I believe I was supposed to do it in style.css under the class I made to put the image. Would it help if I shared some of the code?

Comment: @Rana I've edited the question, please check it out.

Comment: You need to apply this to the image, not the div.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply

```
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: contain;
```

To `img` directly , you can use `id` `class` or `img` directly but last method is not recommended as it will apply to all `img` tags in the document

I have used `red` `background` to show how much area image covers but as `object-fit: contain;` so image ratio's are maintained
[Read this to know more about `object-fit`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)

Use

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

To remove any unnecessary `horizontal` scroll bars as tags have some default `margin` and `padding` . So , here used the `body` tag

```css
.Image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: contain;/*Can be cover , fill , none...*/
  background-color: red;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.hdnicewallpapers.com/Walls/Big/Rainbow/Rainbow_on_Mountain_HD_Image.jpg" class="Image" />
</div>
```

Comment: 'object-fit: fill' worked better for me in this scenario, just thought I just mention that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="fullscreen" /> 

.fullscreen {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    background-image: url(Background.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height:  100vh;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 